# How to compile a sequence of results using ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have a worker actor that receives a message, does a bit of processing and returns a result. And I have a sequence of messages that need to be converted into a sequence of results:

```
object Test {

  case class Message(str: String)
  case class Result(str: String)

  class Worker extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Message(data) =>
            println("Sleeping: " + data)
            Thread.sleep(10000)
            val result = Result(data + " - result")
            println("Sending result: " + result)
            sender ! result
    }
  }

  def test(messages: Seq[Message]): Future[Seq[Result]] = {
    val worker = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props(new Worker))
    val results = messages.map { m =>
        implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)
        println("Sending: " + m)
        val result = worker ? m
        result.asInstanceOf[Future[Result]]
    }
    Future.sequence(results)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val messages: Seq[Message] = args.map(Message(_))
    test(messages).foreach { r =>
        println("Result: " + r)
    }
}
```

}

If I run the above with just "message-1" as an argument it runs fine giving the the output is below:

> Sending: Message(message-1)
>
> Sleeping: message-1
>
> Sending result: Result(message-1 - result)
>
> Result: ArraySeq(Result(message-1 - result))

However say I do it with: "message-1" "message-2" "message-3" then the last message ends up being sent to deadLetters:

> Sending: Message(message-1)   Sending: Message(message-2)   Sleeping:
>   message-1   Sending: Message(message-3)
>
> Sending result: Result(message-1 - result)
>
> Sleeping: message-2
>
> Sending result: Result(message-2 - result)
>
> Sleeping: message-3
>
> Sending result: Result(message-3 - result)
>
> [INFO] [07/15/2016 09:07:49.832]
>   [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/deadLetters]
>   Message [util.Tester$Result] from
>   Actor[akka://default/user/$a#1776546850] to
>   Actor[akka://default/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters
>   encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with
>   configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and
>   'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

I am guessing this is because my calling thread has gone out of scope by the time the last message is sent. How can correctly collect all results into a sequence?

Note that changing my test method to below gives the same results:

```
def test(messages: Seq[Message]): Future[Seq[Result]] = {
    val worker = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props(new Worker))
    Future.traverse(messages) { m =>
        implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)
        println("Sending: " + m)
        val result = worker ? m
        result.asInstanceOf[Future[Result]]
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `actor` doesn't exist, do you mean `worker` here? Not sure why you're seeing dead letters, unless your worker is failing to respond correctly, like maybe using `sender()` improperly. Also, you may want to look into `Future.sequence` to get all of your results as a single `Future`. But I can't say for sure if any of these fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be because my timeout was set too low. Should have been large enough to cover all the work - for example 40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The dumb answer is:

```
Future.traverse(messages)(m => actor ? m).map(_.asInstanceOf[Result])
```

But it might be better to send data all at once:

```
class Worker extends Actor { 
  def receive = {
    case Message(data) =>
      // Convert data into result
      ...
      sender ! result
    case seq: Seq[Message] =>
      ...
      sender ! results

  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Future.traverse(list)(m => actor ? m ... )`. `traverse` is analogous to the combination of a `map` and a `sequence`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens indeed, feel free to edit or answer yourself btw :)